# What is the proper way to type Control-z, Control-c

Tags: random, keyboard, typing

I am just wondering if there is a proper way to type Control-Z, Control-C, ...

Do I use my right hand to hold Control and my left hand to press z? Or do I use my left hand to press both Control and z?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typing, not about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. There is no proper way. Chose what you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use right hand for control and left for the letters, since they are on the left side of course.